# Write simple data to iphone sandbox?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I want to write a small bit of data from my app to the iphone so I can load it when the app next starts. I am going to write the data using NSCoding, but I don't know what I should be specifying as a path. I understand I would write the data to the application sandbox, just not sure how to specify that.

gary

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Several paths are available:
**Documents folder** - its contents persist between application launches and is backuped by iTunes. To get path to it use:

```
NSArray *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES); 
NSString *documentsDirectory = [paths objectAtIndex:0];
NSString *fileInDoc = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];
```

**Caches folder** - almost same, but contents is not backuped by iTunes.

For more information see [Commonly Used Directories](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW12) and [Getting Paths to Application Directories](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/FilesandNetworking/FilesandNetworking.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH21-SW6) in "iPhone Application Programming Guide"

Comment: Thank you Vladimir, the documents folder will probably be best, its only small so it would be good to have it get backed up by iTunes. Much appreciated.